# Проблема с accept() сокеты С++

Tags: c++, сокеты

### main

```
...
CreateListenSocket();
Accept();
...
```

### server.cpp

```
...
void MCServer::CreateListenSocket() {
    // Create a socket and bound it as listening socket
    _ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (_ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket!\tError >> " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }

    // Bind the ip address and port to a socket
    sockaddr_in hint = { 0 };
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(_port);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(_ListenSocket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    // Tell Winsock the socket is for listening 
    listen(_ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    cout << "Listen socket ready\t\tsocket: " << _ListenSocket << endl;
}
...
void MCServer::Accept() {
    _Client = accept(_ListenSocket, 0, 0);       //<<<<<<<<<< PROBLEM
}
...
```

### server.h

```
class MCServer {
...
private:
    int                     _port;
    char*                   _buf;
    int                     _size = 4096;
    SOCKET                  _ListenSocket;
    SOCKET                  _Client;
    fstream                 _file;
    string                  _time;
    string                  _skt;
...
```

При запуске сервера **_Client** получает верное значение. 128 или 126 или 132 например. Дойдя до

> _Client = accept(_ListenSocket, 0, 0);

честно ждет входящего соединения. Когда клиент стучится - срабатывает.
 Затем, когда работа с этим клиентом завершена, сервер закрывает сокет и снова вызывает

```
...
CreateListenSocket();
Accept();
...
```

Но, дойдя во второй раз до

> _Client = accept(_ListenSocket, 0, 0);

**_Client** присваивается космическое число... Типо 99895919816189 и **accept()** принимает соединение без входящего клиента, когда должен по идее ждать реальный вызов. Но клиент еще не коннектился. В чем дело?

Comment: Вы не проверяете результаты функций. Приведенный код является неполным и не воспроизводит проблему. Надо полагать, вы не освобождаете ресурсы после предыдущих вызовов и во второй раз все `bind` `listen` `accept` будут возвращать ошибку. `hint` следует обнулять перед использованием.

Comment: @VTT, каких именно функций ?

Comment: `bind` `listen` `accept` `send` `recv`

Comment: @VTT, так я же заново сокет делаю. Как тогда память эту высвобождать ?

Comment: Читайте документацию к `socket` и прочим функциям.

Comment: В сети же полно примеров реализации TCP сервера/клинета с описанием всего происходящего. Надо просто взять да разобраться, а не велосипедить. Читайте: http://citforum.ru/book/cook/winsock.shtml

Comment: @zed, спасибо за ссылку. Код поправил. Обнуление hint не помогло. Документацию по каждой функции читал уже не раз. Не пойму где собака зарыта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ошибку и хочу поделиться. Надеюсь, поможет кому-нибудь.
Дебагером нашел проблему:

> Возвращает -1 функция `bind(_ListenSocket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));`

Читая MSDN, нашел решение.Необходимо настроить эту функцию:

```
BOOL bOptVal = TRUE;
int bOptLen = sizeof(BOOL);
setsockopt(_ListenSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&bOptVal, bOptLen);
```

> теперь bind() может связывать сокеты, по которым уже передавались
>   данные.

Но проблема не ушла. bind(), listen() и accept() работают так как надо. accept() уходит в ожидание как положено, но при новом входящем соединении не принимает его. Ничего не происходит.
Нашел в итоге ошибку:
Вот тут, в собственном методе:

```
void MCServer::Accept() {
    _Client = accept(_ListenSocket, 0, 0);       //<<<<<<<<<< PROBLEM
}
```

После назначения нового сокета клиенту я не закрываю "слушающий порт". И при повторном вызове метода

```
void MCServer::CreateListenSocket() {
    // Create a socket and bound it as listening socket
    _ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (_ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket!\tError >> " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }

    // Bind the ip address and port to a socket
    sockaddr_in hint = { 0 };
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(_port);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(_ListenSocket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    // Tell Winsock the socket is for listening 
    listen(_ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    cout << "Listen socket ready\t\tsocket: " << _ListenSocket << endl;
}
```

я пытаюсь переназначить уже слушающий сокет не закрыв его должным образом.

> Решение - либо закрывать "слушающий порт" после каждого accept() либо не пытаться создавать его заново. Повторный вызов метода `CreateListenSocket();` ошибочен.